# Do browser cache downloaded javascripts

Tags: javascript, browser

A lot of the time, instead of downloading scripts, people will set the source as a fully qualified URL. As shown here:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

But will the browser cache this file, or will it have to re-download it if the session is reset or if you load a new tab. Would using something like Web Jars or Bower for dependency management keep it from doing so if it did?

Comment: I think the browser will cache this file. If you want to download JS each time your page loads, you can add a parameter something like:

`d=<some_random_number or guid>`

Comment: The main point of using a fully qualified URL is that it does not get downloaded on all the different site. It helps to speed up de loading time.

Comment: Yes, it will get cached. The whole point of using a CDN like this is to leverage the possibility that a user has stumbled upon the library while visiting another website and it's already cached, or, if not, at least deliver it from a network that is specialized in delivering static files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser should cache javascript files according to their HTTP headers, just like any other resource.

Typically a CDN hosted file like you quoted will have a long cache time:

```
$ curl -I https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.7/angular.min.js
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Last-Modified: Mon, 15 Dec 2014 23:03:29 GMT
Date: Tue, 16 Dec 2014 20:07:10 GMT
Expires: Wed, 16 Dec 2015 20:07:10 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Timing-Allow-Origin: *
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: sffe
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
Age: 61071
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=0.02
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```